# save the completed form pdf (using xfdf) to the server rather than displaying it to the user

Tags: php, pdf, xfdf

I have successfully created the xfdf output and correctly filled out the pdf.

```
header ("Content-Type: application/vnd.adobe.xfdf");
print createXFDF($url, $values)
```

How do I save the completed form pdf (using xfdf) to the server rather than displaying it to the user?

Unfortunately pdftk is not an option.

Comment: you're telling it to output to the user. try `file_put_contents('whatever.pdf', createXFPF(...))` instead. and if that function does output anyways, then `ob_start(); $pdf = createXFDF(...); $pdf = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc, the first approach simply saves the xfdf string to file.